# How to strip or redirect a url with question mark sign(?)and equal to (=) sign

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

There was an error in sitemap generation of my website after an update which has led to returning over 700000 crawl errors on my website as a result of that I lost traffic, I need help to redirect the sample url below

From
`http://www.example.com/web-review/en/websitestat?domain=1000places.com`

To
`http://www.example.com/web-review/en/www/1000places.com`

What I want is to replace the `websitestat?domain=` in any url to `www/` and I will be fine because all the 404 errors follow the same pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /en/websitestat\?domain=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /en/www/%1? [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly i only had to add web-review to RewriteRule ^ /en/www/%1? [R=302,L,NE] because it is in a folder which makes it look like RewriteRule ^ /web-review/en/www/%1? [R=302,L,NE]